# How to decrease the space between the matrix elements and the dots in nicematrix package?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I want to decrease the space between the vertical dots and the elements of my matrix. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
    zI-A&\vdots&-B\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\C&\vdots&D
    \end{bNiceMatrix}\begin{bNiceMatrix}
    x_z\\\cdots\\u_z
    \end{bNiceMatrix}&=0\\
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
    z+2&0&0&\vdots&-2&0\\0&z+1&0&\vdots&0&-2\\0&0&z+2&\vdots&0&-1\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
    0.5&1&0&\vdots&0&0\\0.5&0&1&\vdots&0&0
    \end{bNiceMatrix}\begin{bNiceMatrix}
    x_{z_1}\\x_{z_2}\\x_{z_3}\\\cdots\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}&=\begin{bNiceMatrix}
    0\\0\\0\\0\\0
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

As you can see there is an awkward space between the matrix elements and dot lines. How can I decrease this space?
[image: Matrix Example]

Comment: Welcome. Have you seen into the manual `nicematrix` http://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf?  I think that is important also the pag 7 and § 6.3. Regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've read it but I can't find anything on spacing. If it's there, unfortunately, I'm unable to locate or understand it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Here are always some great users who will help you for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement @Sebastiano

Comment: I see no way to change the spacing between the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix` (version 2.2.1, 2019-07-02) to face that problem.

With the classical environmment `array`, you can write:

```
$\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
zI-A&-B\\
\hline
C   &D
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_z\\
\hline
u_z
\end{array}
\right]
=0$
```

[image: Result with array]

With the environment `NiceArray`, if you want to have exactly the same result, you have to use the options
`left-margin` and `right-margin`:

```
\NiceMatrixOptions{left-margin,right-margin}
$\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c|c}
zI-A&-B\\
\hline
C   &D
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c}
x_z\\
\hline
u_z
\end{NiceArray}
\right]
=0$
```

[image: Result with NiceArray]

You can now use the new features of `nicematrix` to draw dotted lines with a `:` in the preamble of the array:

```
\NiceMatrixOptions{left-margin,right-margin}
$\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c:c}
zI-A&-B\\
\hdottedline
C   &D
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c}
x_z\\
\hdottedline
u_z
\end{NiceArray}
\right]
=0$
```

[image: Result with a dotted line of nicematrix]

If you want to use `arydshln` within the environments `NiceArray`, you have to 'free' the specifier
`:` with the option `letter-for-dotted-lines`:

```
\NiceMatrixOptions{left-margin,right-margin,letter-for-dotted-lines=V}
$\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c:c}
zI-A&-B\\
\hdashline
C   &D
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c}
x_z\\
\hdashline
u_z
\end{NiceArray}
\right]
=0$
```

[image: Result with arydshln]

Comment: My sincere congratulations for to have written a new version of `nicematrix` that I like very much. You can see my profile with some answer for this package. Thank you very much for your precious contribute. +1

Comment: Thank you very much. This is excellent news. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

So after looking around I couldn't find anything in the [nicematrix](/questions/tagged/nicematrix) package however I was able to use the [arydshln](/questions/tagged/arydshln) package to solve the problem.
So by using this package and using the NiceArray environment I was able to circumvent my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,nicematrix,arydshln}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\left[ \begin{NiceArray}{c;{1pt/2pt}c}
zI-A & -B\\
\hdashline[1pt/2pt]
C & D \end{NiceArray} \right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_z\\\hdashline[1pt/2pt] u_z
\end{array}\right]&=0\\
\left[ \begin{NiceArray}{ccc;{1pt/2pt}cc}
z+2&0&0&-2&0\\0&z+1&0&0&-2\\0&0&z+2&0&-1\\\hdashline[1pt/2pt]
0.5&1&0&0&0\\0.5&0&1&0&0
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\left[ \begin{NiceArray}{c}
x_{z_1}\\x_{z_2}\\x_{z_3}\\ \hdashline[1pt/2pt] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{NiceArray}\right] &=\left[ \begin{NiceArray}{c}
0\\0\\0\\\hdashline[1pt/2pt]0\\0
\end{NiceArray} \right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Better spacing matrix]

Using the [array](/questions/tagged/array) environment instead of "NiceArray" will fix the problem of "\hdashline" dash lines exceeding the matrix length while allowing the advantages of [nicematrix](/questions/tagged/nicematrix) package.

[image: Matrix, where dash lines don't exceed the martrix width]

p.s: Feel free to edit if you have the time. English isn't my first language.